# Does proj4js is provided with an EPSG dataset?

Tags: proj, proj4js

Is each version of the [proj4js](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js) project delivered with/against a different EPSG dataset version? (like in the [PROJ](https://proj.org/news.html) project)

In other words, if I'm using a specific proj4js version, does it mean that I'm also using a certain EPSG dataset version?

If so, where can I find the reference to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no signs of any initial or later imports of parameters from the EPSG database in the proj4js source code https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js.

It feels like the parameters have been more or less manually copied from some Proj version a long time ago and added/updated if someone has made a bug report. Also the connection with Proj is nowadays only in the name. See https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/issues/357

> proj4js is not much related to proj4. It was originally ported to JavaScript from proj4 a long time ago, and since then it has a completely separate code base and is developed independent of proj4.

These CRS definitions from the SVN repository (perhaps from year 2009)  are probably about as original as they can be https://svn.osgeo.org/metacrs/proj4js/tags/proj4js-1.0.0-RC1/lib/defs/